# OmniPay support for 2checkout API token payments?

Tags: omnipay, 2checkout

Does anyone know how / if it is possible to use token billing? The 2Checkout API supports it and OmniPay supports token billing, but I've not had much luck and a quick look at the Official Gateway code doesn't seem to show support for it?

Anyone doing this / have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can categorically state that it's possible to use token billing, I do so regularly.  I'm not that familiar with 2Checkout but I have used token billing on stripe, paypal, PaymentWall, MultiCards, Fat Zebra and other gateways.

Is there a specific problem you're having that you can illustrate with some example code?

Comment: I've got a [tweet out today](https://twitter.com/volomike/status/729735887832109058) where I'm requesting a compiled list of token-based ecommerce providers. Do you know of any good ones you could link to? It's maddening, trying to weed through the confusing marketing of most eCommerce websites. I've seen it all -- some want passwords just to read their API, some try to hide the fact that they are just a front and price markup on top of Stripe, some are vague about whether they support tokenization or not, some hide their pricing until you enroll, and so on.

Comment: OK just the ones I know of:  MultiCards (EU), PaymentWall (Ukraine), Fat Zebra (Australia), PIN (Australia), eWay (Australia but also international), PaymentExpress (NZ). Stripe of course, and various others that are an API on top of Stripe. There are some that have the capability but it has to be turned on specifically for your  account: First Data.

Answer (score 0):

Does 2Checkout support token billing? Yes, and it works. However, there are some quirks with it:

- You have to turn Demo Mode off on the dashboard or the 2Checkout and OmniPay API doesn't seem to work properly.
- You have to send a Billing Address in order for the transactions to go through. If that doesn't work for you, such as for digital downloads, then you'll want to consider another payment gateway.
- The billing address must contain a customer email and cannot be empty. Again, if that doesn't work well in your sales workflow, then you'll want to consider another payment gateway.
- The billing address must contain a phone number, but CAN be empty.

I discuss this here as well as provide an OmniPay sample code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36807292/105539

Take a look at my project, [TokenPay](https://github.com/volomike/tokenpay). I've weeded through the confusing docs and got it working on 2CO.

P.S. Don't ever forget your sandbox password -- they don't tell you this in the docs, but found out via tech support that their password reset on the sandbox login doesn't look disabled, but is disabled. (It would have been nice if they made that quite clear.) Instead, you'll have to create another sandbox account entirely when you forget a password there.